# What does begin followed by colon and a variable mean?

Tags: syntax, verilog

What does `data_mux` mean here? Is it just a name for the block?

```
if ((PORT_CONFIG == "32") && (P0 == 1'b1))
begin : data_mux
...
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are block names. They are especially useful with `generate` blocks. For example, you can define a `generate` block such as

```
genvar i;
generate (for i = 0; i<10; i++)
begin : structures
    reg my_reg;
    // ...
    .. other block descriptions
    // ...
end
endgenerate
```

Then you can access the block elements later like

```
structures[3].my_reg <= 1'b1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is just the name for the `begin`/`end` block.  Refer to the free [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) (section 9.3.4 *Block names*).  In most cases the block label is optional.