# What is the purpose of the "begin : u" after the for loop?

Tags: verilog

Here is an example where there is a "begin : u" after the for loop.

```
for(i=0; i<8; i=i+1) begin: u
    xem7001_led[i] = (a[i]==1'b1) ? (1'b0) : (1'bz);
end
```

What is the meaning of it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Verilog: what does begin followed by colon and a variable mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990552/verilog-what-does-begin-followed-by-colon-and-a-variable-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a name to a begin..en block. The "u" is the name in this case.

Most `begin..end` block do not need a name.

It depends on the compiler/synthesis tool if a name is required in certain places.

e.g. for some compilers you MUST name the blocks for a `generate`:

```
genvar i;
for (i=0; i<8; i=i+1)
begin : myID
   mygate the_gate(.I0(A[i]),.I1(B[i]),.O(C[i]));
end
```

The name is then used to uniquely identify the parts in the block. In the example above the compiler often makes a name like `myID[0].the_gate(...);`
In other compilers it is optional and if you do not have to specify a name, the compiler then makes up a name to uniquify the section.

---

As dave_59 pointed out:
There are cases where it is not optional. You must have a label if you want to reference a declaration inside the block from outside the block

Comment: There are cases where it is not optional. You *must* have a label if you want to reference a declaration inside the block from outside the block.

Comment: @dave_59 Thank you I'll add that . It is not something I have ever used.

Answer (score 0):

A `begin/end` block creates a scope. Without a label, the scope becomes anonymous and you cannot reference anything inside the block from outside the block. Adding a label also makes it easier to debug. You can also add an `end : u` label, which makes deeply nested `begin/end` blocks easier to read.

When use a generate-for loop, the index iternation number gets appended to the block name.

```
genvar i;
for (i=0; i<2; i=i+1)
begin : U
   reg a = i;
end : U
```

This gets expanded as if you could have written

```
reg U[0].a = 0;
reg U[1].a = 1;
```